# Generate SQL basis on the order in which columns are there in ArrayList

Tags: java, sql, random

I have a class named `TableConnectionInfo` which contains details about the table such as `tableName` and it's `columns`. I have written a method in which I am supposed to generate a random select sql by using the column values from `table.getColumns()` method of each table.

Suppose for table1 it has 10 columns such as-

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
col6
col7
col8
col9
col10
```

Below is my method in which I am trying to generate random select sql using the `table.getColumns()`. Here `table` is the `TableConnectionInfo` object.

```
private static Random random = new SecureRandom();

private String generateRandomSQL(TableConnectionInfo table) {

    int rNumber = random.nextInt(table.getColumns().size());

    List<String> shuffledColumns = new ArrayList<String>(table.getColumns());
    Collections.shuffle(shuffledColumns);

    String columnsList = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rNumber; i++) {
        columnsList += ("," + shuffledColumns.get(i));
    }

    final String sql = "SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" + columnsList + "  from " + table.getTableName() + " where id = ?";

    return sql;
}
```

Below is my `TableConncectionInfo` class which will hold `tableName` and it's `columns` list

```
public class TableConnectionInfo {

    public String tableName;
    public ArrayList<String> columns;

    public ArrayList<String> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(ArrayList<String> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

So the problem with above method is, it will shuffle all the columns in a random way and I will get the result like this-

```
`SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, col3, col1, col5 from table1 where id = ?`
`SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, col7, col2, col3, col1 from table1 where id = ?`
`SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, col8, col1, col2, col6 from table1 where id = ?`
... Other possible combinations
```

And I am looking for something like this. The way columns are inserted in the ArrayList- Suppose this is the order-

`col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10`

Then the columns in my `SELECT SQL` should be in the same order. Meaning-

```
`SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, col1, col3, col5 from table1 where id = ?`
`SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, col7, col8, col9, col10 from table1 where id = ?`
`SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, col1, col4, col5, col6, col10 from table1 where id = ?`
```

It shouldn't be random, like `col1`, then `col5`, then `col2` (which is wrong). It should be-

```
col5, col7, col10
col3, col6, col8, col10

other options
```

**Basically I am looking to have columns in my SELECT sql in the way it was inserted in an ArrayList but in random order. Like- Pick any 4 in the order in which they are inserted or Pick any 6 in the order in which they are inserted or Pick any 7 in the order in which they are inserted**

Comment: Do you want them as they are in your array list or a random order?

Comment: Why are you shuffling the column collection if you want them in a defined order?

Comment: @MattBusche, I want them as they are in my array list but in random order. Suppose `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4` is the order in my ArrayList. Then I need something like this- `col1, col4` or `col2, col3` but not `col4, col1` or `col3 , col1`.

Comment: @Perception, I am doing this becasue I am doing LnP testing so we are trying to replicate production scenario that we about to expect. So that is the reason my intention is to do like this.

Comment: IMHO you need to do the following steps, 1. create a new list p with items in the columns array. 2. shuffle p. 3. create a sublist of rNumber items from p 4. sort it using the sort order of columns array.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Can you provide me an example? By that I will be able to understand more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 solution is as follows

```
private static String getColumns(final List<String> columns) {
    List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(columns);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);

    int rNumber = random.nextInt(columns.size());

    List<String> subList = copy.subList(0, rNumber);
    Collections.sort(subList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return columns.indexOf(o1) < columns.indexOf(o2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
    return StringUtils.join(subList, ",");
}
```

I'm using [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//api/index.html)